# Enable/Disable Jmeter "Duration" Scheduler based on User command line parameters

Tags: docker, command-line, jmeter, scheduler

I have configured Jmeter and dockerized it, have allowed user to pass 3 arguments to the command line via docker run i.e

> 1. Threads
> 2. Loop Count
> 3. Duration

Now, I want to enable user to choose to run a specific test for certain number of loops via loop count or for a specific amount of time via Duration. But the problem is if user provides `loopCount` but doesn't provide `Duration` the test fails, but the test succeeds if Scheduler is disabled in JMeter test. 
However, if the scheduler is disabled, then the user passed value to `Duration` argument won't be honoured. Just wondering if there is a way to Enable/Disable the Scheduler in Jmeter based on argument passed by user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user provides loopCount it takes precedence on duration.

So to control by duration:

- Set -1 in Loop Count

To control by loopCount:

- Set loopCount
- Set a very high value in Duration

Alternatively, edit jmx file and replace:

```
 <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
```

and use __P function:

```
 <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">${__P(enableScheduler)}</boolProp>
```

and to enable duration set in command line:

> -JenableScheduler=true

to disable its use:

> -JenableScheduler=false

If you'd like to learn more about JMeter and performance testing this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.